# Mouse events in C#

Tags: c#

I use Mouse events MouseEnter and MouseLeave with a pictureBox. The Back Color changes with Mouse Enter but do not change in normal with mouse Leave Event.

```
 public void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
 }

 public void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     pictureBox1.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
 }
```

Comment: Is there a question hiding here somewhere? Have you hooked up the events correctly? Have you debugged these at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should remember what the previous color was?

```
 Color prevColor = Color.Black;
 public void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    prevColor = pictureBox1.BackColor;
    pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
 }

 public void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     pictureBox1.BackColor = prevColor;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to know what;s the previous color and change it accordingly. also make sure the control it registered the both the events:

for example, if the color was gray before then:

```
 public void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
 }

 public void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Gray;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems correct.
You should put a breaking point in the mouseleave event.
Maybe the pictureBox1_MouseLeave event is not set correctly.